# Width of the critical window in a random graph

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs, statistical-physics

In an [Erdős–Rényi random graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) $G(n,p)$, [the giant component](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/%7Enovozhil/Teaching/767%20Data/36_pdfsam_notes.pdf) emerges with thresholding function $p(n) = c/n$, where $c>1$.

When $c=1$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we can write or "parametrize" $$p(n) = 1/n + \lambda n^{-4/3},$$ and the largest component is now of order $n^{2/3}$, so not giant, for any $\lambda$. This is the *critical window*, and we can see a *double jump* in the size of  the largest component, from order $\log(n)$ when sub-critical, to $n^{2/3}$ at criticality, to $n$ when super-critical.

But where does this $n^{-4/3}$ comes from?

See for example [this talk](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Egoldschm/Oaxacatalk.pdf), where the critical window is discussed, but its width is not directly discussed.

I am looking at another phase transition and need to evaluate the width $\delta(n) $ of the corresponding critical window, to show that the transition is *sharp*, which requires $\delta(n) / p(n) \to 0$ (notice that $n^{-4/3}/n^{-1} \to 0$, hence the emergence of the giant component is sharp in that case).

How is the width of the transition evaluated in the Erdős–Rényi case, and/or more generally?

Comment: The name "double jump" refers to $p=c/n$ with *constant* $c$, which has three behaviours, for $c<1$, $c=1$ and $c>1$. If $p$ varies more smoothly across $1/n$, the expected size of the largest component varies smoothly (though quickly).  Probably you can find what you need in Chapter 5 of "Random Graphs" by Janson, Luczak and Rucinski, though they work with random graphs with given number of edges rather than with an edge probability.

Comment: In general, is there a general method for finding the "width" of a phase transition? Or does the method vary significantly for each setting? I think my concern is the exact definition of a "critical window" is lacking, so I can see examples of critical windows, but not a general method to find one in a new example (I will look at this textbook, I can also see "Component behavior near the critical point of the random graph process" by Luczak 1990).

Comment: Joel Spencer's exposition of the Phase Transition (https://cs.nyu.edu/~spencer/phasetransition.pdf ) includes in section 1.7 a discussion of a heuristic explanation for the $-4/3$ exponent.  Roughly speaking: If $p=(1+\epsilon)/n$ and $\epsilon=o(1)$, then branching process arguments suggest that the "giant" component has size $\approx 2 \epsilon n$, and the non-giant components have size up to $\approx \epsilon^{-2}$.  This means $\epsilon \sim n^{-1/3}$ is about where you should look for the giant component to start becoming distinguished from the rest.